# conditional UPDATE race conditions

Tags: update, locking, concurrency

In a conditional UPDATE like this:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET my_coulmn = "my value" -- many other updates
WHERE ... -- many conditions
```

Do I have any guarantee that I will only update those records satisfying
my list of conditions (I mean no race conditions with concurrent updates) , whatever it is the DBMS I'm using ?